# Adding main titles from list to graphs in for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, ggplot2

I have two datasets. One with measured concentrations for several days, the other with, for every relevant date, the wind direction.

```
library(ggplot2)

concentrations = data.frame(
  datehour = c("2017-02-15 09:00:00", "2017-02-15 10:00:00","2017-02-15 
               11:00:00", "2017-02-16 09:00:00", "2017-02-16 10:00:00", 
               "2017-02-16 11:00:00"),
  Number = c(3000, 4000, 2000, 6000, 7000, 5000),
  Hour = c(9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 11))

winddir = data.frame(
  Date = c("2017-02-15", "2017-02-16"),
  Wind = c("S", "SW"))
```

I use a for loop to  create a PDF with a graph of every day. This works fine.

I want, however to add a main title to every graph, with both date and wind direction of the relevant day. So I converted the wind direction dataframe into two lists, to use in the for loop.

I am able to use the date list fine, but I do not know how to obtain the wind direction for the main title.

I tried with starting with `c = 1` and then add every loop 1 extra to c and use this to obtain items from wind_list with `paste(wind_list[c])`. This returns a title with the number of c (so "Wind: 1", "Wind: 2" etc.), instead of the wind direction.

```
#creating the lists
wind_list <- as.list(winddir$Wind)
date_list <- as.list(winddir$Date)

#function for plotting graph
plotdays <- function(){
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = concTemp, aes(x = Hour, y = Number))+
                ylab("UFP concentration") + xlab("Hour") + 
    ggtitle(paste("Average UFP concentration per hour on", paste(i),
                  "     Wind:", paste(wind_list[c])))
} 

#the for loop for creating the graphs in 1 PDF

pdf("Test.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
c = 1

for (i in date_list){
  concTemp <- subset(concentrations, grepl(i, datehour))
  if (c == 1){
    wind <-  wind_list[c]
    plotD <- plotdays()
    print(plotD)
    c = c+1
  } else {
    wind <-  wind_list[c]
    plotD <- plotdays()
    print(plotD)
    break
  }
}

dev.off()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would add the wind direction as a new column to the concentration data frame. Then you have both datehour and wind direction for every row and you can easily loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wind lists containing factors and your function seems to read the underlying integers. You could add the wind directions as character instead.

```
#creating the lists
wind_list <- as.list(as.character(winddir$Wind))
date_list <- as.list(as.character(winddir$Date))
```

*Result:*
[image]